# Circumradius of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Lengths of the sides of a triangle, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are given. We are required to find the circumradius of the triangle formed by the vertices $A$, $B$ and $G$, where $G$ is the centroid of the triangle $ABC$. The following is a picture of the problem: (w/o the given values for I don't want this to come across as a homework question)

[image: Problem]

I approached this problem by finding out the lengths of the sides $AG$ and $BG$ of the triangle $GAB$ by using the formula to find the length of the median drawn from any vertex of a triangle. After obtaining these two values(I already know the length $AB$), I used the formula for circumradius given as ABC/4∆ (Where ∆ is the area of the triangle) but I have not obtained the correct answer. I have checked and rechecked for calculation mistakes but nope! None seem to be there.

Is my method correct? Any help would be tremendously appreciated. Thanks so much in advance :) Regards.

Comment: No, that's alright, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $G$ divides the median starting from $A$ and ending at $BC$ in the ratio $2:1$. Furthermore, there is a standard formula for the length of a median provided by [Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem). Combining these, $$AG = \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{AC^2-BC^2+AB^2}.$$ Similarly, $$BG=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{AB^2+BC^2-AC^2}.$$

Now, recall that the area $|ABG|$ of the triangle $ABG$ can be specified in two ways. By Heron's formula, $$
|ABG| = \sqrt{s(s-AB)(s-AG)(s-BG)}, \text{ where } s= \frac{AB+AG+BG}{2},
$$
or $|ABG| = \frac{AB\cdot BG\cdot AG}{4R}$, where $R$ denotes the circumradius of the triangle $ABG$. By equating these two formulas, we find that $$\bbox[border:2px solid blue]{R = \frac{AB\cdot BG\cdot AG}{4\sqrt{s(s-AB)(s-BG)(s-AG)}}, \text{ where } s=\frac{AG+BG+AB}{2}.}$$

Comment: Huh? Since the formula to find the length of the median drawn from vertex A is given by ½[sqrt(2b²+2c²-a²)], I simply divided this by half to get AG. Is this not correct? Oops, maybe not. I didn't learn the formula that you've provided here and it's not required to solve the problem either 'cause in actuality, the triangle given is a right angled triangle for which one can find the coordinates of the centroid as (base/3, height/3), correct?

Comment: *I simply drew another triangle to find out answers for the general case. In the question, a=3, b=4, and c=5 :)

Comment: Oh dear, you should have told me your triangle was right angled! There surely is a very easy formula in that case!

Comment: Sorry :( I wanted to find if my method was correct for the general triangle too. Is the formula for the coordinates of the centroid if a right angled triangle that I gave in my previous comment correct?

Comment: You don't divide by half. The centriod divides all the medians in  the ratio $2:1$, where the $2$ is the path from vertex to centroid, and the $1$ is from the centroid  to the opposite side. Hence, you must divide the length of the median by $\frac{2}{3}$ to obtain $AG$ and $BG$.

Comment: Riight. Thanks ^.^

Comment: You are preparing for some competitive exam? Or some mathematical olympiad?

Comment: Yup. IITJEE advanced(Competitive entrance exam for admission into IIT for undergraduate course in engineering).

Comment: Of course, how would I not know? I gave the exam 3 years ago.

Comment: Oh! Your name sounds Greek so I assumed that u were from Greece, sorry :P

Comment: Did you make it into IIT?

Comment: I got a rank in the late 9000s

Comment: Oh, that's cool! Do you answer questions in the Chem. and Math section too?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: Oh, cool! Stack Exchange is a great website to clear my doubts. (I'm a dropper BTW).

Comment: Yes, you will find lots of people here clearing doubts.

Answer (score 0):

By Euler's formula $R=\frac{abc}{4\Delta}$, the circumradius of $ABG$ is given by

$$ R_{ABG} = \frac{c\left(\frac{2}{3}m_a\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}m_b\right)}{4[ABG]} = \color{red}{\frac{c\, m_a\, m_b}{3[ABC]}} = \frac{4}{3}R\left(\frac{m_a}{a}\right)\left(\frac{m_b}{b}\right)$$
where
$$ m_a = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2} $$
follows from [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem).